# How do I view the contents of a pandas dataframe column untruncated

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

When trying to display a dataframe with a column called 'cmdline', using Jupyter Notebook, the value is being truncated and after a google search I found the following solution:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
df1.head(n = 15)
```

but none of this helped.  The 'cmdline' column is still too narrow and not showing the full text in the column.  Does anyone know of a solution.  The above is all I could find using a Google search.

[image]

edit:

the dataframe was generated by

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("ram-usage.db")
df1 = pd.read_sql("select datetime, cmdline, sum(resident) as resident, sum(shared) as shared from processdata where datetime > '2019-09-25' and datetime < '2019-09-26' group by datetime, cmdline ;", conn)
```

The version of software components I copy and pasted below:

```
Server Information:
You are using Jupyter notebook.

The version of the notebook server is: 5.7.0
The server is running on this version of Python:
Python 3.6.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 12 2018, 14:08:43) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)]

Current Kernel Information:
Python 3.6.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 12 2018, 14:08:43) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.0.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

The notebook itself is run from Docker

```
docker run --group-add=root --rm -p 8888:8888 -e "PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx" -e "USE_HTTP=1" -v "$PWD":/home/jovyan jupyter/scipy-notebook
```

if you want to look at the database file itself it can be downloaded from http://files.kiwiheretic.xyz/ram-usage.tar.gz or http://files.kiwiheretic.xyz/ram-usage.db

Comment: It works for me... Can you add a few lines of your dataframe such that I will try to figure out what is the problem?

Comment: @theletz I've updated the content of the question and have also now supplied the entire database I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you run your code in a different IDE (like Spyder). Then you can view the entire dataframe by simply clicking on the object in the variable explorer.

Comment: I could also do it from the command line, and maybe that would work better also.  I was hoping to avoid installing another IDE especially when I am having ram problems on my machine, which is why I am trying to analyse in the first place.  But I do get how under normal circumstances your suggestion might be helpful.